# Immutable value object with minimal constructor/code

Tags: c#, struct, immutability, record

I need immutable instances of an object where some values are defined at runtime and some at compile time. Ideally, it looks like `Car` because

1. it's immutable
2. no constructor has to be written/updated when values get added/removed
3. values can be grouped together no matter when they are defined and
4. nicely readable when initializing:

   ```
   struct Car {
      public string Name { get; init; }
      public uint CountWheels { get; } = 4; 
    }

    Car carBrand = new() {Name = "CarBrand"}
   ```

The thing is, it does not work:

> A 'struct' with field initializers must include an explicitly declared constructor.

How can I solve this with minimal code?

Answer to comments: any struct, record, class, etc is fine

Comment: You need a public constructor with Name an CountWheels as the parameters

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qef6iY

Comment: First off the purpose of a struct isn't about immutability, however structs should be immutable. In order to achieve immutability you need to make setters private and backing-fields readonly (which is what `init` does behind the scenes).

Comment: Maybe ... [Records (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) ?

Comment: Why are you using a struct instead of a class?  You should be able to do with a class.

Comment: Interesting that `CountWheels` is a float. I've never seen a card with a partial wheel before.

Comment: 'Downgraded' `CountWheels` to uint, thanks for the hint @JoelCoehoorn :-) (it's coming from a more complex object...)

Comment: Okay :) Just wondering if it was counting a spare as 1/2 wheel, or maybe the the "5th wheel" trailer attachment in some trucks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the original object has float for mm and seconds because the firmware requires float. I just happen to use 'car' in my examples as most people know its physical properties such wheels (but I missed that wheels are hardly split into fractions/floats :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your really want a struct:

```
public readonly record struct Car(string Name, int CountWheels)
{
    public int CountWheels { get; init; } = 4;
}
```

But be aware that struct are passed around by value, meaning they are copied each time you pass them around (unless you use `ref`). So, if you have a large struct, it might be a better idea to use a record (class), as it is passed around by reference.

And a record class without primary constructor would look like this:

```
public record Car
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public int CountWheels { get; init; } = 4;
}
```

You can then use the `with` keyword to make copies of records with some properties changed:

```
Car car = new() { Name = "CarBrand" };
var carCopy = car with { CountWheels = 6 };
```

Comment: also very useful to know about `ref` for struct and `with` for record. Exactly the answer I hoped for :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a record:

```cs
public record Car(string Name, int CountWheels = 4);
```

This makes it immutable, and with minimal code.

Comment: that comes close but violates 3): "Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters"

Answer (score 0):

Give it the constructor it's asking for:

```
struct Car {
   public string Name { get; init; }
   public uint CountWheels { get; } = 4; 
   public Car(string name) {Name = name;}
 }

 var carBrand = new Car("CarBrand");
```

I also agree with those suggesting this should still be a class, or maybe a record.

Comment: that comes close but violates 2): With an object that has like 20 parameters in the constructor, it gets messy. I'm curious whether it's possible to make it more elegant in C#. classes or records are welcome but I don't know how to do it.